# How to find a value from a range of cells and place at a specific in google sheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-macros

Suppose I have only one value anywhere at the cell range `C2:Z2`, I want that value at `B2`. What can I do?

I need this solution for all the rows bellow this also. The value might at `C:C` column at one row, at `H:H` column at another, that means it is dispersed at the range but there will be only one value at the range in a row.

Comment: I tried and problem got solved with your answer. But unfortunately my upvote is not counting as I am new to stackoverflow

Answer (score 1):

Place this formula in `B2`:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(TRIM(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(C2:Z), , COLUMNS(C2:Z)))))
```

[image]

---

The formula above works for any type of values.

If your values are numbers then a simpler formula could be used (`MMULT` does row wise sum here):

```
=MMULT(
  ARRAYFORMULA(--(C2:Z)),
  SEQUENCE(COLUMNS(C2:Z), 1, 1, 0)
)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `FILTER()`

```
=FILTER(C2:Z2, NOT(ISBLANK(C2:Z2)))
```

[image]

### Reference:

- [FILTER()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093197?hl=en)

Answer (score 0):

if there will be only one value in the row then a simple sum function will do the job for you. put this in B2 ..

```
=sum(C2:Z2)
```